# ie8 bookmark # click moves page

Tags: hash, internet-explorer-8, scroll, jcarousel, bookmarks

I have a few basic controls that are anchors with no urls, such as

```
 <a id="UP" href="#">UP</a>
```

there's jQuery stuff attaching it to the click event (it's a jcarousel control with overflow hidden)

I understand that onclick needs a return false on it to stop scrolling to "#" on the page to that anchor.  The issue is that on fresh load, no scrolling and the UP click all in view, the page still moves.  Worse, it appears # has 3 or 4 different places!  As I click UP repeatedly, the page moves up and down a few pixels as i click and click.  This is always different than the absolute top where the page originally rendered.

Is it the overflow of the list that is no longer visibile due to the clipping causing this?  Would adjusting heights of the elements so that the list items clip out evenly provide a stop to this?  or is there some other ie8 flaw i'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trail and error, I figured out that I needed to 'return false' the click handler so that it stopped the chain of events from continuing (ie, following the hash).
Further, I adjusted heights on the wrappers and clippers so that they were even, as that was the kicker on the 3 or 4 differnt height moves